# Duplicate error message when leaving a Required list column empty

Tags: 2013, development, custom-form, asp.net, form

I have added an issue tracking list inside my SharePoint 2013 team site. And I set the Description field to be a required column as follow:-

[image]

And inside the “Issue” content type I specify that the Description is Required.

Currently when a user tries to add a new item and he leaves the Description  field empty he will get duplicate errors as follow:-

[image]

So can anyone advice what is the reason behind this? . please note that i have created a new Create form using SharePoint designer, this form which is causing the problem . and here is the markup from the Create.aspx form which responsible for the Description field:-

```
<tr>
<td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
<H3 class="ms-standardheader">
<nobr>Description<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span>
</nobr>
</H3>
</td>
<td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff2{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Comment" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff2',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Comment')}"/>
<SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff2description{$Pos}" FieldName="Comment" ControlMode="New"/>
</td>
                    </tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's one of the UI issues in SharePoint 2013, that when Enhanced Rich Text is selected the required validation message appears twice.

I don't know if there is an update available to fix this (and other issues).

But you can try some JS/jQuery to hide one of them.

Comment: so at-least this does not indicate that i have a problem in my list settings .?

Comment: true, there is no problem with your list settings here. It's SharePoint's bug !